# How to make java graphic fill an image figure according to percentage?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paintcomponent, graphic

I am working on java Paint Component and an empty glass Image as below. My idea is to paint this image with paint color according to percentages given by user. For example, if user put 50% input to my jframe program it will output glass images below with half full colored. I am new to graphic java and how can we do that.

i am thinking of using fillRect(x,y,w,h) as paint graphic but how can i made the calculation given by user, use it on paint fillRect() and display glass fill with graphic accordingly?

What calculation on fillRect() i can apply on this?

[image]    turn to this   [image]

- i use ms paint to draw image above

Comment: Why not simply try it? I mean you calculate 50% of the hight and take the full width and that space is your colored liquid. You could even make it simpler, you got a full liquid glass and an empty glass and you simply display the percentage entered of the full liquid glass overlayed to the empty one.

Comment: oh i get it, we calculate percentage from the image height right, then  how can i implement paint on JLabel? i know there are few post about this but i am hoping for code snippet on how to put paint on jlabel.

Comment: you normally create your own JLabel or JPanel and change it's paintComponent. Like in this example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/painting/SwingPaintDemo2Project/src/painting/SwingPaintDemo2.java but you do not use MS Paint, you use the given functions of Graphics, that should be enough for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The x an width of the drawn rectangle will be constant. So have these constants. (I just trial and error'ed these values

```
private static final int GLASS_WIDTH = 75;
private static final int GLASS_X = 75;
```

So you only need to calculate the y and height values for the rectangle. For that I used a few helper constants

```
private static final int HORIZON = 210;
private static final int GLASS_Y_TOP = 10;
private static final int GLASS_HEIGHT = HORIZON - GLASS_Y_TOP;
```

The `HORIZON` is the bottom most part of the rectangle, the `GLASS_Y_TOP` is the peak of the rectangle at it highest point, and `GLASS_HEIGHT` is 100% of the rectangle.

Knowing these things, I'm able to calculate create a rectangle at 100%

```
private double glassY = GLASS_Y_TOP;
private double rectHeight = GLASS_HEIGHT;
...
rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(GLASS_X, glassY, GLASS_WIDTH, rectHeight);
```

The two new variables `glassY` and `rectHeight` are your values you need to change when the user input value changes.  You can see an implementation of that in the method call to change the values, based off the value passed from the `JSpinner`

```
private void calculateGlassValues(int value) {
    rectHeight = GLASS_HEIGHT * (value / 100.0);
    glassY = HORIZON - rectHeight;
    rect.setRect(GLASS_X, glassY, GLASS_WIDTH, rectHeight);
    System.out.print(rect.getBounds());
}
```

---

Final product

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class PaintPercentImage extends JPanel {

    private static final int GLASS_WIDTH = 75;
    private static final int GLASS_X = 75;
    private static final int HORIZON = 210;
    private static final int GLASS_Y_TOP = 10;
    private static final int GLASS_HEIGHT = HORIZON - GLASS_Y_TOP;

    private double glassY = GLASS_Y_TOP;
    private double rectHeight = GLASS_HEIGHT;
    private BufferedImage image;
    private Rectangle2D rect;
    private int imageWidth;
    private int imageHeight;

    private static JSpinner spinner;

    public PaintPercentImage() {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4IEu.jpg"));
            imageWidth = image.getWidth();
            imageHeight = image.getHeight();
            System.out.println(imageHeight);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(GLASS_X, glassY, GLASS_WIDTH, rectHeight);
        spinner = createSpinner();
    }

    private JSpinner createSpinner() {
        final JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
        SpinnerNumberModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(100, 0, 100, 1);
        spinner.setModel(model);
        spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                int value = (Integer) spinner.getModel().getValue();
                calculateGlassValues(value);
                System.out.println(value);
                repaint();
            }

        });
        return spinner;
    }

    private void calculateGlassValues(int value) {
        rectHeight = GLASS_HEIGHT * (value / 100.0);
        glassY = HORIZON - rectHeight;
        rect.setRect(GLASS_X, glassY, GLASS_WIDTH, rectHeight);
        System.out.print(rect.getBounds());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, this);
        g2.setPaint(Color.YELLOW);
        g2.fill(rect);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(imageWidth, imageHeight);
    }

    public static void showGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new PaintPercentImage());
        frame.add(spinner, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                showGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you say me which program you used to create that gif?

Comment: @LeoPflug I used [Cam Studio](http://camstudio.org/) to capture the screen footage to an avi, then imported the avi to PhotoShop, which I then just save for web, and it automatically turn the avi to a gif